# which spring-data-mongodb version is supported by Spring-boot 2.3.4 because I am getting this error while server startup locally

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot

Failed to introspect Class [org.springframework.data.mongodb.config.MongoConfigurationSupport] from ClassLoader

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/data/support/IsNewStrategyFactory

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.data.support.IsNewStrategyFactory

Comment: Remove indivudual dependencies and use `spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Dependency versions are listed in [an appendix](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.3.4.RELEASE/reference/html/appendix-dependency-versions.html#dependency-versions) of Spring Boot's reference documentation.  In that appendix can see that Spring Boot `2.3.4.RELEASE` uses `3.0.4.RELEASE` of `org.springframework.data:spring-data-mongodb` by default.

If you use Spring Boot's dependency management, either by inheriting from `spring-boot-starter-parent` or importing `spring-boot-dependencies`, you can declare a dependency without a version and Spring Boot's dependency management will give you the correct version automatically. You can learn more about this in the [reference documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.3.4.RELEASE/maven-plugin/reference/html/#using-parent-pom).